# Excel - Sum the number of times a set of criteria happens within a row inside a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have multiple criteria within a range and I am looking to sum the number of times a specific combination of the criteria happens within a row.

Here are my criteria ranges:

```
Segment          Season          Sport

Segment 1        Fall            Baseball
Segment 2        Winter          Running
Segment 3        Spring          Golf
Segment 4        Summer          Basketball
                                 Football
```

I have a report I am trying to build that lists the number of times each sport is listed based off the segment and season.  Within the report each segment and season is in a drop down list and each sport is listed in individual rows:

```
Segment: (Chosen w/Drop down list)
Season:  (Chosen w/Drop down list)

Baseball:   (# of times Baseball & Chosen Segment & Chosen Season appear in the same row)
Running:    (# of times Running & Chosen Segment & Chosen Season appear in the same row)
Golf:       (# of times Golf & Chosen Segment & Chosen Season appear in the same row)
Basketball: (# of times Basketball & Chosen Segment & Chosen Season appear in the same row)
Football:   (# of times Football & Chosen Segment & Chosen Season appear in the same row)
```

Is there any formula or combination of formulas that will check each row within a range for the given criteria, in this case three separate variables, and count the number of times that combination shows up within the range?

To add to this the criteria don't always fall in the same columns.  As an example, if I have five columns in the range I'm checking each of the three categories could be in any column.  This is why I'm looking to check individual rows for each combination.

Comment: You want [`COUNTIFS()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Comment: I tried COUNTIFS(), the problem is the data isn't in defined columns, so the segment could show up in any column as well as the other categories and there's no good way to rearrange the data based of the source.

Comment: Can you say that the values will only appear once per row?

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the values will only appear once per row then use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(($A$1:$E$29=$J$13)+($A$1:$E$29=$J$14)+($A$1:$E$29=$I16),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$E$29))^0)>=3))
```

If not then you need to use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((MMULT(--($A$1:$E$29=$J$13),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$E$29))^0)>0)+(MMULT(--($A$1:$E$29=$J$14),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$E$29))^0)>0)+(MMULT(--($A$1:$E$29=$I16),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$E$29))^0)>0)>=3))
```

[image]

---

The above count 1 per row.  If you want to count each time the sport appears in the same row so if `BaseBall` appears twice in the same row with `Fall` and `Segment 1` then count as `2` instead of `1` use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((MMULT(($A$1:$E$29=$J$13)+($A$1:$E$29=$J$14),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$E$29))^0)>=2)*(MMULT(--($A$1:$E$29=$I16),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$E$29))^0))))
```